# Release build can't find __declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::is_open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm maintaining a rather out of date software stack. Now I had to rerun a tool to create some config files and it does compile and link with the debug configuration but not with the release configuration.

We use Visual C++ 17 enterprise.

I switched on /verbose and the linker gives kind of clue:

```
release 
1>      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(char const *,int,int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PBDHH@Z)
1>        Referenced in nl.obj
1>        Loaded tl.lib(tl.dll)
1>      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1>        Referenced in nl.obj
1>        Loaded tl.lib(tl.dll)

debug
1>      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(char const *,int,int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PBDHH@Z)
1>        Referenced in nl.obj
1>        Loaded tl.lib(tl.dll)
1>      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::is_open(void)const " (__imp_?is_open@?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBE_NXZ)
1>        Referenced in nl.obj
1>        Loaded tl.lib(tl.dll)
1>      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1>        Referenced in nl.obj
1>        Loaded tl.lib(tl.dll)
```

As fas as I recall template programming it is about code generation during compile. The references are created just to save code size.

So why does the visual c++ compiler creates a is_open method in debug and not in release??

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] of your code that you can show us?

Comment: Sorry, no. That's not possible. The workaround is using the debug variant and put the error to the backlog.